# Executing RegEx in Bash with Perl

Tags: arrays, regex, string, bash

in Bash I have an array `names` that contains the string values

```
Dr. Praveen Hishnadas
Dr. Vij Pamy
John Smitherson,Dr.,Service Account
John Dinkleberg,Dr.,Service Account
```

I want to capture only the names

```
Praveen Hishnadas
Vij Pamy
John Smitherson
John Dinkleberg
```

and store them back into the original array, overwriting their unsanitized versions.

I have the following snippet of code *note that I'm executing the regex in Perl (-P)*

```
for i in "${names[@]}"
do
        echo $i|grep -P  '(?:Dr\.)?\w+ \w+|$' -o | head -1

done
```

Which yields the output

```
Dr. Praveen Hishnadas
Dr. Vij Pamy
John Smitherson
John Dinkleberg
```

Questions:

1) Am I using the look-around command `?:` incorrectly? I'm trying to optionally match "Dr." while 
   not capturing it

2) How would I store the result of that echo back into the array names? I have tried setting it to

```
i=echo $i|grep -P  '(?:Dr\.)?\w+ \w+|$' -o | head -1

i=$(echo $i|grep -P  '(?:Dr\.)?\w+ \w+|$' -o | head -1)

i=`echo $i|grep -P  '(?:Dr\.)?\w+ \w+|$' -o | head -1`
```

but to no avail. I only started learning bash 2 days ago and I feel like my syntaxing is slightly off. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lookahead says "include `Dr.` if it's there". You probably want a negative lookahead like `(?!Dr\.)\w+ \w+`.  I'll throw in a leading `\b` anchor a a bonus.

```sh
names=('Dr. Praveen Hishnadas' 'Dr. Vij Pamy' 'John Smitherson,Dr.,Service Account' 'John Dinkleberg,Dr.,Service Account')

for i in "${names[@]}"
do
        grep -P  '\b(?!Dr\.)\w+ \w+' -o <<<"$i" |
        head -n 1
done
```

It doesn't matter for the examples you provided, but you should basically always quote your variables. See [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Maybe also google ["falsehoods programmers believe about names".](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

To update your array, loop over the array indices and assign back into the array.

```sh
for((i=0;i<${#names[@]};++i)); do
    names[$i]=$(grep -P  '\b(?!Dr\.)\w+ \w+|$' -o <<<"${names[i]}" | head -n 1)
done
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help this works great! Although one thing that confuses me is if I have the input "Dr Alex Jones" and modify the regex to make the period character optional eg (?!Dr\.*) it fails to recognize the pattern and outputs "Dr Alex" instead

Comment: Try changing it to `(?!Dr\W)`or something like that. Regex begins to crumble when you have the full range of creative human obfuscation to deal with but this should be easy still.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this for the regex?

```
(?:^|\.\s)(\w+)\s+(\w+)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/29I5dU/1)

```
(?:             # Non-capturing group
   ^|\.\s       # Start match if start of line or following dot+space sequence
)
(\w+)           # Group 1 captures the first name
\s+             # Match unlimited number of spaces between first and last name (take + off to match 1 space)
(\w+)           # Group 2 captures surname.
```

Comment: unfortunately this yields:
. Praveen Hishnadas,
. Vij Pamy,
John Smitherson,
John Dinkleberg

I believe my problem may be executing it in Perl mode